# Cascading Dropdown Validation is failing in MVC Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

**Problem Statement:**

I have created a cascading dropdown for Country and State using Jquery and Json,everything is working fine.I'm able to bind data for Country and data for State on change event of Country.Only problem what i'm facing is cascading validation for Country and State.

On opening the View iff I click create button without selecting/entering any values for the controls it is showing validation message for all.If i select Country and click create, it is not showing validation message for state even if no value is selected for State.

What i'm doing wrong?? I think i'm doing something wrong in Script part of the view !!!

***Please see the attached images for more details:***

**Image 1 :** *When I click create button it is showing validations for all controls.*

[image: Image 1]

**Image 2 :** *After selecting Country drop-down if i click create button,validation for state is not appearing why??*

[image: Image 2]

**View Code:**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cityModel.CountryID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cityModel.CountryID, new SelectList(Model.ddlCountryStateCity.ddlCountry, "Value", "Text"), "Select Country", new { id="CountryID",onchange="GetddlState()",@class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cityModel.CountryID)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cityModel.StateID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cityModel.StateID, new SelectList(Model.ddlCountryStateCity.ddlState, "Value", "Text"), "Select State", new { id="StateID",@class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cityModel.StateID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cityModel.CityID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cityModel.CityID, new { @class = "form-control" })
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cityModel.CityID)
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="form-group">
               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cityModel.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cityModel.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cityModel.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Script Code:**

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetddlState() {
        $("#StateID").empty();
        $("#StateID").append("<option value='0'>Select State</option>");
        var countryID = $('#CountryID').val();
        var Url = "@Url.Content("~/MasterConfigGeneral/GetddlState")";
        $.ajax({
            url: Url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { CountryID: countryID },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#StateID").empty();
                $("#StateID").append("<option value='0'>Select State</option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
                    $("#StateID").append("<option value='" + optiondata.Value + "'>" + optiondata.Text + "</option>");
                });
            }
        });
    }

 </script>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Try This:

```
 @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function GetddlState() {
         var countryID = $('#CountryID').val();
         var Url = "@Url.Content("~/MasterConfigGeneral/GetddlState")";
         $.ajax({
           url: Url,
           dataType: 'json',
           data: { CountryID: countryID },
           success: function (data) {
            $("#StateID").empty();
            $("#StateID").append("<option value='' selected='selected'>Select State</option>");
            $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
            $("#StateID").append("<option value='" + optiondata.Value + "'>" + optiondata.Text + "</option>");
            });
        }
    });
 }

</script>
}
```

Comment: It is working for all scenarios except one.Initially validation works for both country and State Controls.After selecting value in Country,without selecting value in state validation is working for State(using Option value='').Validation for state fails after selecting value in state, if i re-select option in Country to Select Country again and i click create button validation for state not working...Why???

Comment: Validation is working fine with new scenario: After selecting Country and State drop-down if i re-select Country to select option, State should reset to select option,which is not happening..!!!Even after selecting country to select option, State is having old values

Comment: @VishalIPatil Plz see updated answer.it will work fine.

Comment: No it is not happening, again same problem..!!!After resetting value in Country drop-down to "Select Country",script is not clearing old values in State drop-down with "Select State" option showing on top.

Answer (score 0):

```
             type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({"id": idd}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Adding these three parameters under `$.ajax` will solve the problem